# Pointer array swap without direct access to array

Tags: c++, pointers, swap

Trying to get my character to move in a matrix using commands. But I cant get the movement quite right.

Here is the code uploaded to WandBox to save space in question: [WandBox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Pg5zrg9H7dpTcw4G)

Expected:
I expect that when i press the w key, the dot on the map '*' moves up. by swapping the two pointers.

Result:
Swapping does nothing, even tho the pointers do change.

```
void Player::update(Node * neighbors[8], const char c,Node * self)
{
    switch (c)
    {
    case 'w':
        move(neighbors[1],self);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

//This is right issent it?
void Player::move(Node * newspot, Node * oldspot)
{
    Node* temp = newspot;
    newspot = this;
    oldspot = this->standingTile;
    this->standingTile = temp;
}
```

I don't get it. I Did try a few different things, like a pointer to an array pointer, so hopefully my example doesn't look crazy.

Comment: `move()` is assigning pointers.    The pointers are passed by value, so the assignments are not visible to the caller.    You need to rewrite so the function swaps the pointed-to nodes, not the pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I figured it out, Turns out what i'm trying to do is called "multiple indirection".

as @Peter pointed out it was non trivial to just swap to pointers in this way.

```
virtual Node* update(Node** neighbors[8], char& c);
```

Was what I needed, where I pass an array of pointers to the pointers in the stored array so that I may swap them in the top level.

```
int* myArrayOfInts[MAP_SIZE*MAP_SIZE];
```

Where I can keep an accurate list of all objects.

Then when I need to manipulate it as a 2d array:

```
int*(*map)[MAP_SIZE] = (int*(*)[MAP_SIZE])myArrayOfInts; //Cast as 2d Array temporarily.
```

Now I can treat map as a normal 2D array of pointers.

Now it becomes trivial to adjust the parent array by passing a pointer to the pointer array as:

```
&map[x][y]
```

Or in my case Storing them in an array of array pointer pointers....

```
Node** neighbors[8];
neighbors[0] = &map[x][y];
```

Then I can pass that to a function, allowing me to swap values around without copying and moving whole objects.

Yo dog, I herd you leik pointers, so we put pointers to your pointers in arrays of pointer pointers.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
void Player::update(Node * neighbors[8], const char c,Node * self)
{
    switch (c)
    {
    case 'w':
        move(&neighbors[1],&self);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

void Player::move(Node ** newspot, Node ** oldspot)
{
    Node* temp = *newspot;
    *newspot = this;
    *oldspot = this->standingTile;
    this->standingTile = temp;
}
```